# Building hierarchical Makefile with GNU Make

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a project divided in modules, each hosted in a directory, say:

```
root
|_module_A
 |_module.cpp
 |_Makefile
|_module_B
 |_Makefile
|_main.c
|_Makefile
```

main.c depends on targets defined in Makefiles related to `module_A` and `module_B`.

I want to write my `root/Makefile` with respect to targets defined in Makefiles of both modules.

Now, I know that I could use the `include` directive, but the problem here is that targets and filenames in `module_A` and `module_B` aren't prepended with their directory, so I get something like this:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `module.o', needed by `main.c'.  Stop.
```

There is a good way to solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Where do you want to put the object files (e.g. `module.o`)?

Comment: In the same (sub-)directory of the relative source files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this, none of them perfect. The basic problem is that Make is good at using things *there* to make things *here*, but not the other way around.

You haven't said what the targets in `module_B` are; I'll be pessimistic and suppose that `module_A` and `module_B` both have targets called `module` (different source files, different recipes), so you really can't use `include`.

The biggest choice you have to make is whether to use recursive Make:

If you don't, then `root/Makefile` must know how to build `module_A/module` and `module_B/module`, so you'll simply have to put those rules in. Then you must either leave the redundant rules in the subdir makefiles (and run the risk that they'll drift out of agreement with the master makefile), or eliminate them, or have them call the master makefile recursively (which you wouldn't have to do very often, but it sure would look silly).

If you do, then `root/Makefile` will look something like this:

```
main: main.o module_A/module.o Module_B/module.o
    ...

main.o: main.c
    ...

%/module.o:
    $(MAKE) -C $(@D) $(@F)
```

This will work well enough, but it will know nothing about dependencies within the subdirectories, so it will sometimes fail to rebuild an object that is out of date. You can `make clean` (recursively) beforehand every time, just to be on the safe side, crude but effective. Or force the `%/module.o` rule, which is less wasteful but a little more complicated. Or duplicate the dependency information in `root/Makefile`, which is tedious and untidy.

It's just a question of your priorities.

Comment: Good, thorough answer if you _must_ use recursive make, though I'd say that's a bad idea in the common case.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you write the makefile in a non-recursive way?

[Recursive Make Considered Harmful](http://aegis.sourceforge.net/auug97.pdf)

Comment: I could, but I've inherited all those modules with their Makefile and, since I'm lazy, I'd like to reuse them as much as possible.Makepp has a wonderful facility (load_makefile) that loads all definitions in a Makefile placed in a given subdirectory, prepending the subdirectory to the targets defined there. I was wondering if there is a way to do something similar in Makefile, instead of copypasting all the targets in the various Makefiles and prepending the subdirectory manually.

Comment: @akappa, short answer: yes, but it wouldn't be reliable. A short `sed` script could prepend the directory name to the targets, but if the makefile used relative paths anywhere (and there are a *lot* of ways a makefile can do that) the script would be unable to correct them.

Comment: @Beta: thank you, I think I'll write a single Makefile, it's easier after all (and a lot cleaner)